# Is burning bamboo sticks really prohibited in Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, rituals, puja

There is a popular [Zee News video circulated around](https://youtu.be/bIl3MQ2tOns?t=70) claiming that burning bamboo sticks are prohibited in Hindu religion. That video also shows how harmful it can be for the environment inside the house.

But I want to know which scripture said that? And does that scripture mention any reason for it?

Comment: During cremation a dead body is placed on bamboo  stretcher which is burned along with the body. so I highly doubt of the claim that burning bamboo is prohibited

Comment: @shanu "bamboo stretcher which is burned along with the body", I remember hearing multiple times that it's not supposed to be burned with body and video said the same. Even in my hometown that stretcher is usually thrown in river etc not burned

Comment: Earlier time people used to cook meal by burning bamboo/sticks since they didn't had gas. So zee news is talking about which time?

Comment: @Rishabh give me sometime to get that video link. Right now I have whatsapp video only.

Comment: Looks related: https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/heres-why-hindus-must-never-burn-agarbatti-at-homes

Comment: Bamboo Tree is associated with Rudra & Skanda as it's said in puranas that Bamboo originated from them. Also there is relation between Bamboo & Shree Krishna as his flute was of Bamboo. Bamboo tree jungle  takes many years to grow and were used in construction of Homes & Temples during ancient times.May be it's prohibited because of high usability and slow growth factor.

Comment: @Rishabh added the video